# RelativeLayout elements complicated iteraction

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Inside RelativeLayout is some ammount of images/views (I add them dynamically from code). I position them(items) by Y axis (the can be on the same Y value) and align to left (all of them).I need 'em to stick to left : if there is item on the way to stick left parent border , stick to that item, if no , stick to border.
[here is what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIRf4.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement.

Comment: Please post your sample layout which you want to design

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari  now you understand what i mean?

Comment: please post your sample code what have you done then we can help

Comment: first of all I want to know is there any way to make it with the layouts?

Comment: You want your items to be filled column by column??? Means Column 1 top to bottom filled, then shift to Column to and fill top to bottom, and so on. Am I right now?

Comment: I add views to relativelayout dynamically and they could be on the same Y coordinate value, so they should stack to left ,but if they have view on their way, they should stick to that element.